# how to update selectionTracker when adapter is renewed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've implemented a tracker to my recyclerView, and it works fine.
my problem is when I add some items to my recycler or even renew the whole adapter, the tracker won't work.

the crash is out of range for returning `key` from dataArray which is passed to  `ChatItemKeyProvider` in the creation of `SelectionTracker`

the code for `getKey` is this:

```
    @Nullable
override fun getKey(i: Int): String {
    return mPokemonList[i]!!._id
}
```

what I've tried so far:

everyTime I add some data to my adapter,I set the tracker in adapter to null and renew my tracker again, but still its crashing. the example code is like this :

```
                tracker = null
            chatAdapter.setTracker(null)
            tracker = SelectionTracker.Builder(
                chatId,
                chatRecycler,
                ChatItemKeyProvider(newResult, myUserId),
                ChatItemDetailsLookup(chatRecycler),
                StorageStrategy.createStringStorage()
            ).withSelectionPredicate(
                SelectionPredicates.createSelectAnything()
            ).build()
            chatAdapter.setTracker(tracker)
```

my question is how to update my tracker when data is updated?

Comment: i have the same problem, could you resolve this problem ?

Comment: @hvar90 unfortunately I couldn't find any way to update selection when removing or adding new items to the list! I used diffutil and it's not working for item deletion! I've seen that if you use stableId, it might fix your problem! in my case, it didn't work. I suggest trying stableId.